# Spring + Hibernate don't create a Query

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Can not create table in MYSQL, because something wrong with my Query or parameters in Entity, i don't understand. Everything i checked, everything i saw, but dont work. Please help

My Interface

```
public interface CourseDao extends JpaRepository <Course, Long> {
    
    List <Course> findCourseBycourseName (String keyword);
    
    @Query (value = "select * from courses as c where c.course_id in (select e.course_id from enrolled_in as e where e.student_id = :studentId)")
    List <Course> getCourseBylistStudent (@Param ("studentId") Long studentId);

}
```

Entity Course

```
    @Entity
@Table (name = "courses")
public class Course {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "course_id", nullable=false)
    private Long courseId;
    
    @Basic 
    @Column (name = "name", nullable=false, length = 45)
    private String courseName;
    @Basic
    
    @Column (name = "duration", nullable=false, length = 45)
    private String courseDuration;
    
    @Basic
    @Column (name = "description", nullable=false, length = 45)
    private String courseDescription;
    
    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn (name = "instructor_id", referencedColumnName = "instructor_id", nullable = false)
    private Instructor instructor;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable (name = "enrolled_in", 
                                     joinColumns = {@JoinColumn (name = "course_id")}, 
                                     inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn (name = "student_id")})
    private Set<Student> listStudent = new HashSet<>();
```

Student Entity

```
 @Entity
@Table (name ="Students")
public class Student {
    
    @Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy  = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column (name = "student_id", nullable = false)
private Long studentId;

@Basic
@Column (name = "first_name", nullable = false, length = 45)
private String firstName;

@Basic
@Column (name = "last_name", nullable = false, length = 45)
private String lastName;

@Basic
@Column (name = "level", nullable = false, length = 45)
private String studentLevel;

@ManyToMany (mappedBy = "listStudent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set <Course> courses = new HashSet<>();

@OneToOne (cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JoinColumn (name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", nullable = false)
private User user;
```

Log

```
 Error creating bean with name 'courseDao' defined in spring.dao.CourseDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List spring.dao.CourseDao.getCourseBylistStudent(java.lang.Long); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List spring.dao.CourseDao.getCourseBylistStudent(java.lang.Long)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at spring.CourseSystemApplication.main(CourseSystemApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List spring.dao.CourseDao.getCourseBylistStudent(java.lang.Long); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List spring.dao.CourseDao.getCourseBylistStudent(java.lang.Long)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at 
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List spring.dao.CourseDao.getCourseBylistStudent(java.lang.Long)
        Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: A query exception occurred [select * from courses as c where c.course_id in (select e.course_id from enrolled_in as e where e.student_id = :studentId)]
            ... 48 common frames omitted
```

In other interface everything work, but with CourseDao have some problem, if you know, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Use `nativeQuery=true` when using MySQL queries in spring data jpa.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "your query")
```

Comment: Tnx, real work, why i dont think about that. Nice day bro